# Optional parameters in django urls

Tags: python, django

I want to achieve this in Django

1. List all items
2. Get only one item

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    if pk is not None:
         product = self.get_object(pk)
         serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    else:
         products = Product.objects.all()
         serializer = ProductSerializer(products)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If pk is in URL take only one product if not take all list.

How can I achieve that in URL? What I'm doing is this

```
re_path(r"(?P<pk>\d+)", ProductView.as_view(), name="product"),
```

But 'pk' argument is required here. I don't want the pk to be required but optional.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define two paths:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', ProductView.as_view(), {'pk': None}, name='products'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    # …
]
```

The `{'pk': None}` part specifies what value to pass.

An alternative is to make the `pk` optional, so:

```
def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
    if pk is not None:
         product = self.get_object(pk)
         serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    else:
         products = Product.objects.all()
         serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

then you make again two paths with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', ProductView.as_view(), name='products'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    # …
]
```

Comment: When I add two paths, in swagger the APIs are being duplicated

Comment: @maca: the proper way to do this is therefore not to use `get` twice, but simply make a `ModelViewSet`, that will point to different methods...

Comment: @maca: see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/ By doing that, the two really point to different methods, hence with different documentation.

Comment: @maca: the routers then define several paths that will point to `retrieve` and `get` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/